# Couchebase create global secondary index in Couchebase

Tags: java, database, indexing, where-clause, sql++

```
bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex(indexName, fields, where, true, false);
```

I need to know `where` parameter, in case

```
create index index_ABC on bucketname(fieldname) where xyzField=XYZ
```

given: `XYZ` is a variable.

Comment: Can you please give more details? Im not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be constant value.

CREATE INDEX `def_name_type` ON `travel-sample`(`name`) WHERE (`type` = "User");

This is called partial index. Index def_name_type indexes on name field of all the documents where `type` = "User". WHERE clause in CREATE Index is optional. If it is present exact same thing needs to be present in Query otherwise index will not be selected.

Example:
SELECT META().id FROM `travel-sample` WHERE name = "xyz" AND `type` = "User";